# UIAlertView dismissed by button click or by NSTimer result in error on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nstimer, uialertview, avaudioplayer

I am programming for the iPhone. I haven't programmed for twenty years so am rather new to the whole objective programming thing. I have an UIAlertView that pops up when a sound is played with AVAudioPlayer. The user can dismiss the UIAlertView by clicking the button or wait until the sound ends (dismissed by an NSTimer call).

However, if the UIAlertView was dismissed by button before the NSTimer call, the program crashes. How do I check if the UIAlertView is displayed?

I tried the condition currentAlert.visible==YES but that crashes also if the view was already dismissed. What is the value of an UIAlertView object once it is dismissed?

Here's the code:

```
-(void) dismissAlert
{ 
     if(currentAlert.visible==YES){
     [currentAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}


-(void) playSound:(NSString *)filename 
           volume:(float)volume 
           ofType:(NSString *)type 
         subtitle:(NSString *)text 
            speed:(float)speed 
            loops:(NSInteger)loops 
{
    //playSound
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:type];
    theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]
                                                                             error:nil];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    theAudio.volume=volume;
    theAudio.enableRate=YES;
    theAudio.rate=speed;
    theAudio.numberOfLoops=loops;
    [theAudio prepareToPlay];
    [theAudio play];

    //display alert
    if (text!=nil) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
                                                        message:text 
                                                       delegate:self  
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        currentAlert=alert;
        [currentAlert show];
        duration= theAudio.duration/speed;
        [NSTimer    scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:duration   
                                            target:self  
                                          selector:@selector(dismissAlert)    
                                          userInfo:nil 
                                           repeats:NO];
        [alert release];
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It would be nice and helpful, if you could post properly formatted code.

Comment: oh, and you should use better tagging.

Comment: Am learning. Haven't touched programming for twenty years.

Comment: note that in objective the method name can be written in several lines. I use to do so less scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Implement this method, which will be called when the user taps one of the buttons in the UIAlertView.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    // user tapped a button, don't dismiss alert programatically (i.e. invalidate timer)
}
```

Docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIAlertViewDelegate/alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:

Answer (score 0):

When a user taps a button the method `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` is called on the `UIAlertView`'s delegate so that's where you should do your work

First you may need to keep a reference to the timer so create a new ivar

```
// .h
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *alertViewTimer;

//.m
@synthesize alertViewTimer = _alertViewTimer;

- (void)dealloc;
{
    [_alertViewTimer release];
    //.. Release other ivars
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)playSound:(NSString *)filename 
           volume:(float)volume 
           ofType:(NSString *)type  
         subtitle:(NSString *)text 
            speed:(float)speed 
            loops:(NSInteger)loops
{

// .. the rest of your method

self.alertViewTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:duration
                                                       target:self
                                                     selector:@selector(dismissAlert)
                                                     userInfo:nil 
                                                      repeats:NO];

// .. the rest of your method

}
```

Then in the delegate method implement the dismissing and invalidation of the timer:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [alertViewTimer invalidate];
    self.alertViewTimer = nil;

    // .. Do whatever else you want to do.
}
```

and you can leave your `dismissAlert` method a little simpler

```
- (void)dismissAlert
{ 
    [self.currentAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

**Solution 2**

Another potential way to do this would be to replace this:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:duration
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(dismissAlert)
                               userInfo:nil 
                                repeats:NO];
```

with:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(dismissAlert) withObject:nil afterDelay:duration];
```

and then implement

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self 
                                             selector:@selector(dismissAlert) 
                                               object:nil];

// .. Do whatever else you want to do.
}
```